# Ansible - Loop Variable

Tags: ansible, yaml

i'am trying to start application with a ansible playbook.

the variable inst got all the required software id's:

```
WEB
TS3
SQL
....
```

how can i create a loop for all the software id's and run the same command on all of them?

```
---
- name: "start sw"
  become: yes
  command: "swstart {{ inst }}"
  retries: 3
  failed_when: ( instance_start.rc not in [ 0 ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first of all define your list as a variable on your playbook .
After that you can use

> with_items

Like that:

```yaml
---

- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    softwares:
    - WEB
    - TS3
    - SQL
  vars_files:
    - /softwares.yml # if you need to import data from file

  tasks:

  - name: display your softwares using debug module
    debug:
      msg: "An item: {{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ softwares }}"
```

I hope that this can help you to fix your issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks -  but i have different software id's on different servers.

Comment: I think you can get all servers id's first of all after used it from a file

Comment: @bigMre Just imagine that the `softwares` var in the above example is defined in your inventory at host level rather that in the playbook. The result will be exactly what you expect and the task does not need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Use `with_items` as below

```yaml
---
- name: "start sw"
  become: yes
  command: "swstart {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ inst }}"
```

Documentation:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items

Comment: Or consider using `loop`, which is what the linked documentation actually suggests. `loop: "{{ inst }}"`.

Comment: somehow it gives me a syntax error... either with loop or with_items

Comment: @bigMre Somehow you did not [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67059391/edit) your question to provide a full [MCVE](/help/mcve) that one can actually run to reproduce your problem and give a meaningful answer.